# Content/resource Build Action in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

When you build a C# project with some files that you want to include in the executable, you typically set the build action to Resource. However, I haven't figured out a way to retrieve those files at runtime aside from [`Application.GetResourceStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596994(v=vs.110).aspx), which is not available in .NET Core.

I'm trying to build a cross-platform .NET Core console app, so how can I embed files in the executable that I can then retrieve at runtime?

Comment: If the Resources option doesn't work for me and need some file in build folder I would use CopyAlways option in Right Click on File -> Properties -> Build Action = None, Copy to output Directory = Copy Always

Comment: @vidriduch This won't embed the file in the executable, though. I'm trying to make my program as compact and easy to distribute as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream) method instead. [`Application.GetResourceStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.getresourcestream?view=netcore-3.1) is part of `PresentationFramework.dll` assembly, which will come in WPF with .NET Core 3.x